# linux server sudden slow downs without high load

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, load-balancing, load-average

I have a web server with the following specs:

i7-4770K, 32GB RAM, 500GB SSD (1000 Mbit/s connection).

The server is dedicated for the server side of an Android dating application. The app has around 15k daily users.

The app regularly experiences slow downs to the point where it barely serves any content. The slow down happens suddenly, and I’ve noticed that when the app is fast the load is around 2-3 (top command), and when it becomes extremely slow, the load drops to bellow 1.

What could be the issue? I’ve attached screenshots of the top command showing which processes are using the CPU/RAM, etc..

this is the apache config:

```
StartServers 5
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10

ServerLimit 2048
MaxRequestWorkers 1200
MaxConnectionsPerChild 10000
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 300
Timeout 300
```

output of some commands during the slow down

Command# top
[image: output of top command during the slow down]

Command# sar -q
[image]

Command# uptime
[image]

Comment: What happens to the amount of connected users? How much network traffic is there?

Comment: How may i check the amount of connected users and network traffic?

Comment: The first part you should know (15k a day, but how many during the slow down).  The total amount of bytes received by the server since boot is reported by `/sbin/ifconfig`. Keep an eye on `RX bytes` if it increases faster than 100 million (MB) per second the LOCAL network is saturated.

Comment: The limit to how much traffic the server can receive is also set by the internet connection.  Does it have gigabit internet or is it slower?

Comment: /sbin/ifconfig  output: 
enp2s0: RX packets 115156814  bytes 17472665382 (16.2 GiB)
lo: RX packets 749631  bytes 153420347 (146.3 MiB)

Comment: Please update your question with how fast it is increasing.

Comment: yes, server Connectivity: 1000 MBit

Comment: If the network can be confirmed to not be overloaded, the very CPU hungry `mysqld` would be my next bet.  You can use `lsof` to see what processes are connected.  Hopefully some SQL guru can chime in if needed and move to chat if needed.